# Can't pull image from amazon ECR. stuck at Pulling fs layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, amazon-ecr

Hi currrently I'm trying to pull image from Amazon ECR from cluster nodes. But it got freeze when using docker pull

[image]
after a while it timedout
`error pulling image configuration: download failed after attempts=6: dial tcp 12.123.123.12:443: i/o timeout`

What I've done are

1. cluster node network is private and public
2. create endpoint for ECR, 3 endpoints API, DKR, S3 Gateway
3. nodes security groups outbound allow to cluster security group and endpoint security group

When I apply manifest yaml it got pullimageerror. then I shell into nodes, after login and try to pull it got freeze at download fs layer. I'm out of idea where to check further.

It's fine if I allow node public access but the point is I need it to be in private network.

here is my S3 policy

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Check if the disk is full, also try to pull the same image directly on some other instance. if it doesnt work try restarting docker service

Comment: Thank you for your reply. disk is not full. I have restarted docker service but didn't work either. I can pull if I grant it public access. But if using private access it can't

Comment: Can you post the S3 Gateway Endpoint policy.

Comment: I have edited and added S3 policy

Comment: Instead of the above one make the policy specific as below.  {
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Access-to-specific-bucket-only",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::prod-ap-southeast-1-starport-layer-bucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: still not working after in stuck at Pulling fs layer it got timedout
`error pulling image configuration: download failed after attempts=6: dial tcp 12.123.123.12:443: i/o timeout`
how should I check further

Comment: Can you add port 443 to the security group of the vpc endpoint

Comment: vpc endpoint already inbound all traffic